# USB Wireless devices not registering, how do I fix this?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, usb-device

I put Kali Linux on a small little laptop for testing and demonstration purposes, but I've run into an issue I've never seen before.

Every wireless interface I plug in through USB shows up as shown in the attached image, it's all mangled up and doesn't actually work, and I've no idea what's wrong!

The interface appears as `'wlx00c0ca97dc12'`. Really jumbled up.

Any help would be appreciated, point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Here's my `ifconfig`:

```
wlx00c0ca97dc12: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 2e:a6:a9:c6:0a:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`lsusb`, it's device 11:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. UB91C
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:2052 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c80 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `iwconfig`:

```
wlx00c0ca97dc12  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

Hopefully, that's enough information, I can post more if needed.

**Edited for further clarification:**

While editing this, Hooray! I managed to get it working. The long ass interface names were the issue. I took mosvy's advice and returned the interface naming scheme back to normal. I can now connect just fine through my dongle :)

`touch /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` Fixed it for me!

I was expecting a more usual interface name like `eth1`, `eth2`, etc. I assumed that this messed up version of the interface name meant something was wrong, as I'm unable to connect to an access point using the USB Wireless Devices that I plug into the machine. For example, I plug in my Alfa Wireless USB dongle and it won't allow me to connect to any AP's, and I receive a system message saying "activation of network connection failed".

I thought it may have been a driver issue, but installing Kali Wireless drivers yielded no results. If these names are accurate as they're the naming conventions used in Kali and not actually an error, then I must be looking at a different kind of issue.

Comment: In what way doesn't the device _as named_ not work? Please [edit] your question to provide concrete facts to support this.

Comment: You'll have to get used to it. That's the modern way to name interfaces in linux ;-) (google for "predictable interface names" -- "predictable": at least they haven't lost their sense of humor). If your system works like mine, you can restore the old-style naming (`wlan0`, `eth0`, `usb0`, etc) by creating an empty udev rule in `/etc` which overrides the one from `/lib`:  `touch /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`.

Answer (score 0):

`touch /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` Fixed it for me! New Interface naming conventions were the issue, reverting to the old ones fixed it. Thanks to mosvy :)