# How to remap network interfaces on boot time?

Tags: debian, system-installation, network-interface, portability

It turns out that I'm trying to create a portable distro while getting prepared for any kind of hardware failure.

I'm creating (or restoring) a Debian distro by [multistrap](https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-example) (or from my backups) and requiring the resulting disk to be bootable on a new (mostly compatible) hardware, including [a VirtualBox machine](https://superuser.com/a/756731/187576).

As I [asked before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466195/65781), one of the few required things for a "portable distro" is handling the network interfaces' names.

For example, on the real machine, first ethernet device is named as `enp2s0` and in VirtualBox, it's named as `enp0s3`. How am I supposed to generate a `/etc/network/interfaces` file on boot?

Is there a more generic way to remap the network interface names (by symbolic links, maybe) and let every application use those names (the role names) without the necessity to know the real network interface names of the underlying hardware?

Comment: one way to fix it is to [revert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557144/usb-wireless-devices-not-registering-how-do-i-fix-this#comment1035104_557144) to the old interface names: eth0, etc. A tricky issue is to make it prefer the fastest, not the first interface -- `ifupdown` is pretty inept at handling it nicely.

Comment: The `touch /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` trick didn't work on Debian 10.

Comment: It works for me on Debian 10, both on a vanilla version, and on my customized one.

Comment: Also see the "I don't like this, ..." section [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

Comment: Here is my `ifconfig` output after a reboot: https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/fe29b009ba02f283bf34abe55b9dee27 What is the black magic behind `touch .../80-net-setup-link.rules`?

Comment: The `/etc/udev/rules.d` files override those from `/lib/udev/rules.d`. The interface renaming is called from `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`.

Comment: Regarding to PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames page: I can't say I don't like it, so it seems to worth to bear the new naming scheme.  So it boils down to re-generating the necessary files (such as `/etc/network/interfaces` on boot time and use the old network interface names as "role names" in scripts via a converter program, like `lan_eth=$(get-iface "eth0")` in place of `lan_eth="eth0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could solve this.

The most familiar way would probably be to disable the new network interface naming scheme by using the boot option `net.ifnames=0`, or by overriding `/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link` with `ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link`, or by masking the udev rule file that actually implements the new-style names with `ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`... see [the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames) for more info on various ways to revert to the classic naming scheme. Then you could rewrite your `/etc/network/interfaces` to just use `eth0`.

The most flexible way would probably be to stop using static `/etc/network/interfaces` and switch to NetworkManager. It will automatically default to using DHCP on a network interface that has an active link, if there is no further configuration. That would automatically handle even cases when you have multiple NICs but only one (not necessarily the first one) is actually plugged in.

Or you could do your own thing, by writing a custom script that will read `ip link show` output (or the links in `/sys/class/network`) and rewrite `/etc/network/interfaces` (or whatever your actual network configuration file is) to suit. Then you could add the script as a systemd service with `Wants=network-pre.target`, `Before=network-pre.target`, `After=module-init-tools.service` and probably `DefaultDependencies=no`. This should allow the script to run as part of the early system set-up, after all modules have been loaded but before the network configuration begins.

Comment: I'm already using [my own network-manager](https://github.com/aktos-io/aktos-nm) so I'll stick with "do your own thing" approach. Wouldn't that be an issue if I completely omit `/etc/network/interfaces` for the rest of the system services if I register my (or anyone's) network manager to the `systemd`? Doesn't anyone need to use that file directly?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up your suggestions, you are suggesting to re-generate the `/etc/network/interfaces` on every boot (which satisfies my needs). What is the "predictable name" (thus the `ID` section) of `ip link show` output? Is it the sequence number of the command output?

Comment: If  `ip link show` is tricky to parse, you could just look at links in `/sys/class/network` to find the network interface names, make an exception for `lo`, and then either test the interfaces for active links, rename them as you see fit, or whatever.